# Laravel Join query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Hello guys i am new in **PhP** and **Laravel**. I want to use a join query in **laravel** and have written the code below, but it gives me an error.

```
$data = DB::table('employees')
->join('contact_details', 'employees.id', '=','contact_details.employee_id')
          ->join('education', 'employees.id', '=', 'education.employee_id')
          ->join('addresses', 'employees.id', '=', 'addresses.employee_id')
          ->select('employees.first_name','employees.id','employees.gender','education.id','education.school','education.subject','addresses.village')
          ->where('employees.id', '=',$id)


          ->get();
  return "$data";
```

and the error is

```
 ErrorException in ProfileController.php line 66:
 Array to string conversion

 in ProfileController.php line 66
 at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Array to string conversion',        'E:\xampp\htdocs\djiafg\app\Http\Controllers\ProfileController.php', '66',      array('id' => '72', 'data' => array())) in ProfileController.php line 66
      at ProfileController->view('72')
     at call_user_func_array(array(object(ProfileController), 'view'), array('id'    => '72')) in Controller.php line 80
   at Controller->callAction('view', array('id' => '72')) in       ControllerDispatcher.php line 146
  at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(ProfileController), object(Route), 'view')   in ControllerDispatcher.php line 94
  at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
  at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
 at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
```

Comment: Post your error too in question and remove that extra paranthesis from `($id)` i.e. `->where('employees.id', '=',$id)`

Comment: @Nazir Noori : It seems $id would be with parenthesis but your error report may well clarify the actual situation.

Comment: Don't post the error. That would be too easy.

Answer (score 3):

Laravel has a special functions for joins, called models.

> The Eloquent ORM included with Laravel provides a beautiful, simple ActiveRecord implementation for working with your database. Each database table has a corresponding "Model" which is used to interact with that table. Models allow you to query for data in your tables, as well as insert new records into the table.

A model can have one or many. This will return one row from the user table data.

Add this to your model which fetch data from your employees table.

```
public function user() {
  return $this->hasOne('app\User', 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

now you can run to dump the user id. (you need a model called "Employees" which is connected to your table "employees")

```
$employees = Employees::get();
dump($employees->user->id);
```

I hope this works!

See more at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent

Answer (score 0):

Just try to remove the space before select and make the where condition as follows

```
$data = DB::table('employees')
    ->join('contact_details', 'employees.id', '=','contact_details.employee_id')
    ->join('education', 'employees.id', '=', 'education.employee_id')
    ->join('addresses', 'employees.id', '=', 'addresses.employee_id')
    ->select('employees.first_name','employees.id','employees.gender','education.id','education.school','education.subject','addresses.village')
    ->where('employees.id',$id)
    ->get();

    return view ('profile',compact('data'));
```

Comment: Is that $id is array ? Can you try to print the $id